# How to maintain time along with date while JS Date format in material-table?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-table

So I want to convert js date format ,

```
ex: 2020-12-23T07:05:58.000Z
```

To ISO date format in material-table but I also want to maintain time.

For this I tried ,

```
 const columns = {
      title: "Date",
      field: "date",
      type: "date",
      dateSetting: { locale: "en-GB" },
 }
```

But it gave the output as: 12/23/2020 but I also want the time as 12/23/2020 07:05.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution if any one wants to convert they can do this,

```
  const columns = {
        field: 'receivedOn',
        title: 'Date',
        type: "datetime",
    },
```

and it will give proper date with time as : 12/23/2020, 12:35:58 PM